# How do I format this data in r?

Tags: r

I am currently working with data thats in a log file and looks like this:

```
Subject: MS1989, Characters: G3, Position: TL, Block: 2, Reaction Time: 957 ms

Subject: MS1989, Characters: 7A, Position: TR, Block: 2, Reaction Time: 220 ms
```

How do I convert this so that it looks more like this:

```
Subject Characters Position Block Reaction Time

MS1989 G3 ...
```

This may have been answered before, but I really dont know how to word this, so searching is difficult. Maybe reshape could be usefull here, but this doesnt seem to be either long or wide format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the data into a text file "tidy.txt":

```
Subject: MS1989, Characters: G3, Position: TL, Block: 2, Reaction Time: 957 ms  
Subject: MS1989, Characters: 7A, Position: TR, Block: 2, Reaction Time: 220 ms
```

Then:

```
library(tidyverse)

untidy  <- read_csv("untidy.txt", col_names=FALSE)
tidier <- untidy %>% 
          separate_rows(col=1:ncol(untidy), sep=":") %>% 
          distinct()
colnames(tidier)  <- as.character(tidier[1,])
tidy <- tidier[-1,]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there could be much better solutions,

```
library(tidyr)
df = data.frame(x = c("Subject: MS1989, Characters: G3, Position: TL, Block: 2,  Reaction Time: 957 ms",
  "Subject: MS1989, Characters: 7A, Position: TR, Block: 2, Reaction Time: 220 ms"))

df$y <- gsub("Reaction Time:", "", 
         gsub("Block:", "",
              gsub("Position:", "",
                   gsub("Characters:", "",
                        gsub("Subject:" ,"",df$x)))))

df$x <- NULL
df <- df %>% separate(y, into = c("Subject", "Character", "Position", "Block", "Reaction"),
            sep = "[,]")

df
   Subject Character Position Block Reaction
1  MS1989        G3       TL     2   957 ms
2  MS1989        7A       TR     2   220 ms
```